# How can I pre-cache image thumbnails?

Tags: nautilus, performance, automation, thumbnails

I have several frequently-updated folders that contain thousands of high resolution JPGs. The first time I browse into any of them, it takes a long time for Nautilus to generate all the thumbnails.

How can I automatically generate and cache them ahead of time during the night?

Comment: You might just open the folders (perhaps `cd some_toplevel_folder ; find . -type d -exec nautilus {} \;`) before you drop off for the night.

Comment: To the person responsible for the anonymous downvote: It's not obvious to me what I did wrong here. Care to explain?

Comment: This solution should work for images as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-thumbnails

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for it in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607056). I have not tested it, will do so later on. Give it a go, if its broken maybe we can fix it.