# Nautilus isn't displaying thumbnails for my NEF files (photo raw)

Tags: nautilus, photo-management

I'm not getting any thumbnails in nautilus for my NEF files (photo raw).  Is there an easy way to repair this?

Comment: Is this still reproducible?

Comment: @Braiam Don't know about 14.04, but in 13.10 I had to install those extra packages as in my asnwer for it to work.

Answer (score 33):

By default, Ubuntu doesn’t display thumbnails for NEF files. But you can try (as explained in [this blog post](http://vdimic.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/nef-files-preview-ubuntu/)) installing UFraw.

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw
```

And if itś not already existing, create a thumbnailer file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/ufraw.thumbnailer`, with content :

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/ufraw-batch --embedded-image --out-type=png --size=%s %u --overwrite --silent --output=%o
MimeType=image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;
```

This file basically say to exec `ufraw-batch` (with the good parameters) on any file with the specified mimetypes (including `image/x-nef`).

Comment: +1, a small correction needed, it should be `/usr/share/thumbnailers` instead of `/usr/share/thumbnailer`

Comment: I have a Panasonic camera, which creates RW2 files. I had to add the MIME Type of `image/x-panasonic-raw2;` to the end of the last line above. Works a charm after that! :)

Comment: This does not work out the box on ubuntu 18.04, below answer from @Dan works great.

Comment: This works in 19.04.

Comment: I can confirm this also work in 19.10, without even needing to restart Nautilus. *NOTE:* in my case I had to add `image/x-panasonic-rw2` to the list of MIME types in the `ufraw.thumbnailer` file.

Comment: E: Package 'ufraw' has no installation candidate

Comment: In order for this to work on RAW files which already had a preview generated, I had to clear the thumbnails cache with ``nautilus -q; rm -rf .cache/thumbnails/* .thumbnails/*`` and then start Nautilus again. After what, it works like a charm! Thanks :) https://gist.github.com/h4cc/13450db3d4a7457f9b38

Answer (score 13):

Okay, most of the answers here either don't work from Ubuntu 19.10, or are slow because they process the RAW files.

NEF files (and probably lots of other formats) have embedded JPEG's previews in them, which is a lot faster to extract. And lo' and behold, the default thumbnailer for Gnome supports them, but they're not enabled, here's how to enable it:

- you have to edit the file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer` to add the missing MIME types.
- Here's the file before:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=image/png;image/bmp;image/x-bmp;image/x-MS-bmp;image/gif;image/x-icon;image/x-ico;image/x-win-bitmap;image/vnd.microsoft.icon;application/ico;image/ico;image/icon;text/ico;application/x-navi-animation;image/jpeg;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/tiff;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-tga;image/x-icns;image/x-quicktime;image/qtif;
```

- You may append just `image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;` for NEF if you want, or you can add all RAW formats (I just did that):

```
image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;
```

Comment: Beautiful, the actual raw processor was taking seconds per file to generate the thumbnail and would've taken an hour for my directory.  This is much quicker and more helpful for just casual browsing.

Comment: I can confirm this works in ubuntu 20.04 (which currently doesn't have ufraw or gnome-raw-thumbnailer packages for some reason).

Comment: this is so much better than installing additional software, and it also renders faster. wonderful solution! Tested and works on Linux Mint 19.3

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for x-sony-arw (A6000) on 21.04 for some reason...

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 22 LTS for NEF files.

Answer (score 8):

You can install the following packages, and Nautilus will start displaying thumbnails for NEF files without having to do any manual configuration.

### 18.04 and newer:

```
sudo apt install libopenraw7 libopenrawgnome7 gnome-raw-thumbnailer
```

It seems the `libopenraw1` and `libopenrawgnome1` are no longer available in 18.04 and above, they were replaced by `libopenraw7` and `libopenrawgnome7`. In fact, the 2 libraries don't seem to be required to generate the thumbnails and can be skipped. However, if you include them, the generation of the thumbnails becomes much faster.

### 16.04 and earlier:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenraw1 libopenrawgnome1 gnome-raw-thumbnailer
```

source: [Ubuntu Foums - viewing nikon NEF raw files?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907877&p=11608460#post11608460)

Comment: not work at ubuntu 18.04. Can't find package libopenraw1 and libopenrawgnome1.

Comment: This works great on ubuntu 18, but the packages are libopenraw7 or -dev, just remove the 1 and `tab`, you will quickly see what the correct package is. I used `s/1/-dev` for both.

Comment: @dogmatic69 Thanks for the info! I updated my answer. However, there's no need to install the `-dev` packages. It should be enough to use `libopenraw7` and `libopenrawgnome7`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it seems the `libopenraw*` libraries are not needed, and `gnome-raw-thumbnailer` is enough. But having them installed is making the generation of the thumbnails A LOT faster.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 I get `Unable to locate package gnome-raw-thumbnailer`. Simply editing `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer` as per https://askubuntu.com/a/1204150/292055 worked for me in 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

ufraw is no longer available so in order to have thumbnails in nautilus in **20.04** you need something different. I'm using dcraw, however it only converts to ppm or tiff. And the gnome thumbnails need to be png. So in this solution I use ImageMagic convert.

Here is my solution:

1. Install dependencies:

```bsh
sudo apt install dcraw ImageMagick
```

2. create a script to combine the 2 commands

```bsh
sudo nano /sbin/rawthumbnailer
```

and put the paste the following in it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/dcraw -c -w -v -h "${1}" | /usr/bin/convert - -resize x"${2}" png:"${3}"
```

Don't forget the execution flag:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /sbin/rawthumbnailer
```

3. create the thumbnailer script in /usr/share/thumbnailers:

```bsh
sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/raw.thumbnailer
```

The contents should read as this

```bsh
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/sbin/rawthumbnailer
Exec=/sbin/rawthumbnailer %i %s %o
MimeType=image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;
```

4. Restart nautilus:

```bsh
nautilus -q
```

If you tried before and didn't succeed you should delete the thumbnails

```bsh
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

or at least the failed thumbs dir

```bsh
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
```

The script needs to be in /sbin, /bin or /usr... as the generation is happening using the bwrap and there are only some directories binded in it. I tried to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266322/what-additional-thumbnailers-are-available-and-how-do-i-install-them) to have the script in home, but it didn't work for me.

Also I was unable to make it work without the script file. Not sure if it is possible or not, but I prefer to have a simpler solution with less files if possible.

Answer (score 2):

At ubuntu 18.04 just install `gnome-raw-thumbnailer`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-raw-thumbnailer
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using gnome 15.10 , got non problem with nikon.nef and canon.cr2 ,but no way to show thumbnails of nikon.NRW

- I can get preview only by script using dcraw , but not in gnome-thumnailers

Here the script i set in nautilus :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="$@"
for i in $FILES
do
echo "Processing image $i ..."
/usr/bin/dcraw -e  $i thumb.$i
done
```

Of course this make a new jpeg on side of the pic....