# Thumbnails for NEF are too big

Tags: 18.10, thumbnails

My thumbnails are huge: a 20MB Nikon NEF image has a 18 MB thumbnail generated in PNG format in .cache/thumbnails.

Thumbnails for NEF did not show by default in 18.10. I followed [Nautilus isn't displaying thumbnails for my NEF files (photo raw)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283072/nautilus-isnt-displaying-thumbnails-for-my-nef-files-photo-raw)

How can I reduce the size of my thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 19.04: Thumbnails for NEF are now 50-100k.

To get thumbnails in nautilus I followed the first answer given in [Nautilus isn't displaying thumbnails for my NEF files (photo raw)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283072/nautilus-isnt-displaying-thumbnails-for-my-nef-files-photo-raw), by installing ufraw followed by adding the thumbnailer entry described there.