# Starred files function became broken, can you help me fix it?

Tags: nautilus, 21.04, thumbnails

I have a problem where I can not STAR any new files or folders in Ubuntu 21.04 until after I reboot.
Additionally, any files shown in a 'symlink folder window' cannot be starred, nor do they show as 'Starred' even if the actual file is starred.

This is possibly related to another question [RAW Thumbnails in Nautilus (Sony .ARW)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354371/raw-thumbnails-in-nautilus-sony-arw) where I was attempting to get Raw thumbnails to display. The [method there](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1484) didn't work well, so I reversed it, it was quite simple affecting only 2 files.

- modify `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer` to include RAW image mime-types.
- `sudo mv/path/to/rawtherapee.thumbnailer /usr/share/thumbnailers/`
- `rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/*`

However, a few days after this I noticed that Starring files didn't work. I am certain those 2 changes are undone correctly, but the coincidence seems to suggest otherwise.

An additional effect I've noticed, (is it normal?): when I Star/Unstar an image file (jpg, png) the thumbnail is regenerated (a white file with a clock icon appears for a moment before the preview reappears). This does not happen with pdf.

I have created a new user & the same problem exists for that user. Log out/in has no effect. But, as mentioned, after a reboot files created during the previous boot can then be Starred, but subsequent new ones cannot until the next boot.

My file system is `ext4` & files or folders created are just in `~/Documents`

**Update:** Additional troubleshooting steps:

I ran `journalctl -f` & watched for activity when clicking a STAR.
On a existing file, which I can star, I see output in the journal as the file becomes starred.

```
8月 01 22:35:34 Sulaco systemd[5919]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
8月 01 22:35:34 Sulaco dbus-daemon[5933]: [session uid=1000 pid=5933] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
```

When I click on a new file, which I cannot star, there is no output in the journal.

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer here besides: file a bug report. If it smells like a bug ... ;-)

Comment: I did file a bug report, but now I dont think it is... unless everyone is unable to star new files they make. 
Why do you say I wont get an answer?