# Custom thumbnailers don't work in GNOME

Tags: gnome, thumbnails

I wanted to have .chm and .epub files thumbnailed in Nautilus. I followed instructions presented here: https://askubuntu.com/a/266323/119832 with no effect. Provided thumbnailers and their installation scripts didn't change anything. So I created my own script and tried to pass it into configuration. Still no effect. I've tried *.thumbnailer file approach:

```
$ cat ./.local/share/thumbnailers/chm.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/home/mariusz/Pobrane/nds-thumb/chm-thumb %i %o
MimeType=application@vnd.ms-htmlhelp;
```

And configuring GNOME directly:

```
$ gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@epub/enable" -t boolean 'true'
$ gconftool-2 -s "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@epub/command" -t string "/usr/bin/epub-thumbnailer %i %o %s"
```

And files still have this icon:

[image: icon]

I've tried to undo customizations:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers
$ gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers
```

and removed thumbnails already stored in ~/.thumbnails.

Both images and videos are thumbnailed properly.

OS and GNOME version:

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.4.1
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Is there a way to solve this problem or to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gconf` approach is for Gnome 2 only. For Gnome 3 (Ubuntu 11.10 onwards) the `~/.local/share/thumbnailers` (or `/usr/share/thumbnailers`) is the correct one.

And your problem is that you mixed the 2 approaches. This line:

```
MimeType=application@vnd.ms-htmlhelp;
```

Should actually be:

```
MimeType=application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp;
```

Basically, replace **`@`** for **`/`** and it should work. And I also recommend adding `application/x-chm` to the list, just in case.

You see, `@` was just an (ugly) workaround gconf required since `/` was not a valid char for key names (it is used to indicate key hierarchy).

But apart from the now obsolete `gconf`, mime types are always defined with `/`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you and sorry for late response.