# eBook Cover Images in Nautilus?

Tags: unity, nautilus, epub

Is there any plugin that would allow the cover images from eBooks to be seen in  Nautilus file directory windows (in Ubuntu 14.04 / Unity)? I'm looking for something that would give me cover images like I see for PDF eBooks in Nautilus.

Comment: I don't know how to do it for ebooks, but [here](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2011/11/24/xfig-thumbnailers-with-gnome3nautilus3/) you can find hints on how to setup your custom thumbnails.

Comment: Check out [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266322/what-additional-thumbnailers-are-available-and-how-do-i-install-them).

Comment: @Glutanimate - thanks, that fixed it. I upvoted both the question and the answer you referenced. Since this was answered by your question, it's functionally a duplicate; but if you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks!