# How to open a directory and view images if it contains a large number of image files (~70,000)?

Tags: nautilus, image-processing, batch

I am working on an image processing project. For that I have a directory which contains around 70,000 images. As I process them in multiple stages I save the intermediate images in another directory. But when I want to see it I can't, as when I open the directory, due to the number of files the file manager stops responding.

Even if I somehow manage to open it, I fear that the image viewer will not respond, as I am under the impression that they try to put a few images in cache to load faster.

I tried to open the images from terminal. I can open one image at a time in this case but I can't view it as a gallery, which is equally bad as I need to view many images to know that the results are satisfactory.

Comment: I suggest you portion this directory, by using the command line, to `cp` (copy), or `mv` (move) images/image folder-directories around. This way you can get it done step by step.

Comment: I have been doing it for now. But after some time it becomes too much of side work. So I am looking for a better alternative.

Comment: After trying multiple options, I finally came to conclusion that I should show the images programmatically.
As I was already using opencv for my project, I wrote a python script to display each image sequentially.
Thanks everyone for taking time in answering.

Comment: Hi Prince, it would be useful for everyone if you could share the python script.

Comment: @jokerdino Sorry, it was a long time ago. I don't have that script now. I will keep in mind to share scripts in future.

Comment: Have a look at this previous question about a similar problem.
It's a workaround which may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-thumbnails/201997

Comment: If I open one image in the terminal, then I can click "next" in the image viewer... I am wondering what your script did that improved on that functionality

Comment: @karel: Nautilus doesn't deal well with that many files in the same folder even in compact view which doesn't display thumbnails. It took over a minute for me a few years back even with just a few thousand files.

Answer (score 0):

70k image files are a *lot*.

The first thing I can suggest is to disable thumbnails (In nautilus > preferences, choose the "preview" tab, select  Never).

[image: thumbnails]

Then you can test the various image viewers/manipulators (the standard viewer, gthumb, shotwell, darktable, etc etc ) and see if someone is reasonably fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already disabled the thumbnails. In process of trying out different image viewers and window managers. But I believe this is not much related to the image viewer.