# How to generate thumbnails in advance (pdf mostly)

Tags: command-line, pdf, thumbnails

I have a rather large set of documents (150 GiB ~5000 files) and would like to know how to pre-generate thumbnails, preferably from the command line, so that when I navigate to the folder, I don't have to wait for them to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I decided to use one of the scripts from [this recommendend AskUbuntu post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-thumbnails)

I just copied it to a file, saved it to my ~/bin (in my case as generate-thumbnails) and issued `chmod +x` on it. Then I just navigated to the ~/Documents folder and ran `generate-thumbnails *` I don't know How long it took, but when I  woke up the next, all was good.

Be aware that you might need to install `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0`:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
```

Since it doesn't waste time generating duplicates, it would be a low impact cron job (after the first run).

From a terminal prompt `crontab -e` If it is your first time editing the crontab, it will ask you to choose an editor. I just use nano and I'll give the keyboard commands for it.

Add the following to the end...

```
0 4 * * * /home/user/bin/generate-thumbnails /home/user*
```

- <kbd>Ctl</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>   Will save the file.
- <kbd>Ctl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>   Will exit. (it you have a syntax error it'll let you know and you can just `crontab -e` again. This sets up cron to run at 4am every morning.
- If you want to change it or look at other cron options.. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto is a good place to find out options.

Main reasons for running this script:

- it will recurse through sub-directories
- it is aware of duplicates
- it works equally well for videos
- it will work in other DE's (I switch often based on what I'm doing)
- it would be good for a cron job

Here is the script.... (Thanks [James Henstridge](https://askubuntu.com/users/12469/james-henstridge) !!

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

from gi.repository import Gio, GnomeDesktop

def make_thumbnail(factory, filename):
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    # Use Gio to determine the URI and mime type
    f = Gio.file_new_for_path(filename)
    uri = f.get_uri()
    info = f.query_info(
        'standard::content-type', Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, None)
    mime_type = info.get_content_type()

    if factory.lookup(uri, mtime) is not None:
        print("FRESH       %s" % uri)
        return False

    if not factory.can_thumbnail(uri, mime_type, mtime):
        print("UNSUPPORTED %s" % uri)
        return False

    thumbnail = factory.generate_thumbnail(uri, mime_type)
    if thumbnail is None:
        print("ERROR       %s" % uri)
        return False

    print("OK          %s" % uri)
    factory.save_thumbnail(thumbnail, uri, mtime)
    return True

def thumbnail_folder(factory, folder):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            make_thumbnail(factory, os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

def main(argv):
    factory = GnomeDesktop.DesktopThumbnailFactory()
    for filename in argv[1:]:
        if os.path.isdir(filename):
            thumbnail_folder(factory, filename)
        else:
            make_thumbnail(factory, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bash script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-creating-a-image-thumbnails-from-shell-prompt.html) (kudos to Tim) . From the link the following script and comments:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
djpeg $i | pnmscale -xysize 48 38 | cjpeg -opti -progr -qual ‘75%’ > TN_$i
echo $i processed
done
```

- This will make thumbnails for files ending in .jpg and create a thumbail with name TN_*.jpg. Adjust the parameters to your liking.
- For thumbnails, you quite often don’t want to use imagemagick or convert or whatever; for my normal size (48×38), it creates a whopping huge 50K jpg when there are other ways of getting them much much smaller:
- This keeps the average image-size down to about 1K – rather more suited to a page of thumbnails!
- pnmscale will be installed by default
- Installing djpeg and cjpeg

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo-progs
  ```
- edit: wont work with PDF

---

Ignoring the advice in the comment about using imagemagick ...

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

and use this as a similar method as above but in this case using the convert command from IM:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="$@"
for i in $FILES
do
echo "Processing image $i ..."
/usr/bin/convert -thumbnail 100X100 $i $i.png
done
```

Here is an [elaborate document](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/) on thumbnailing using IM. You can specify height, width and lots more. Example from the link:

> For example, this converts JPG images into GIF thumbnails in a "thumbs" sub-directory that was just created 100 pixels wide and 100 pixels high
>
> ```
> mkdir thumbs  
> mogrify  -format gif -path thumbs -thumbnail 100x100 *.jpg
> ```

---

Oh the title is specific about PDF. Using IM...

```
convert -thumbnail 100x100 1.pdf 1.png
```

Comment: Does Nautilus pick up these files?

Comment: If not directly it should be 1 F5 away from picking up.